# Importing Google Earth into C# Application

Tags: c#, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to run Google Earth in a c# application.  I did some research and found that the Google Earth API will stop working on December 12, 2015, however, my c# application needs to work longer than that.  Is there a way to import Google Earth into a C# Application without using this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives.  As stated in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130910/google-earth-plugin-deprecated-which-alternatives), you can use:

- [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/CesiumViewer/index.html)
- [D3js](http://d3js.org/)
- [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/)

Another alternative is [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

These may not be a perfect match, but depending on your requirements, they may suit your needs well enough.
As to the C# aspect of it, you will need to dig deeper into whichever option you prefer, but I doubt it will be much more complicated than dealing with Google Earth API.

Note: The "Plug pulling" on Google Earth API happened due to security issues.  For more info go [here](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I have kmz files that can only be opened in Google Earth, so I'm not sure these will work

Comment: You can convert kmz files into gpx or some other suitable format for whichever option you decide to go with. 
I believe Cesium is able to read kmz (or kml) files, not sure about others though.

Comment: The alternatives you mentioned are for web/js, not for C#